# C# SQL Server data to long array

Tags: c#, arrays, sql-server

I am trying to use C# with a SQL Server database and I have a problem.

I have an array something like that actually original array have a 10001x1 size

```
long[] lvl = { 0, 7200000, 15840000, 25920000, 37440000, 50400000, 64800000, 80640000 }
```

When I try to take same `long[]` array from the database, I am getting an error.

```
        string sorgu = "select * from paragon";
        var komut = new SqlCommand(sorgu, baglanti);
        var reader = komut.ExecuteReader();


        IList<long> lvl = new List<long>();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            lvl.Add((long)reader["Paragon"]); 
        }

        reader.Close();
        reader.Dispose();


        long ns = Convert.ToInt64(textBox1.Text);
        long sns = Convert.ToInt64(textBox2.Text);
        long nsxp = lvl[ns];
        long snsxp = lvl[sns];
        long toplam = nsxp + snsxp;

        for (int i = 0; i < lvl.Count; i++)
        {
            if (toplam < lvl[i])
            {
                textBox3.Text = Convert.ToString(i - 1);
                break;
            }

        }
```

[İmage 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pl1Nz.png)
[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y4Wvw.png)

Comment: what is the error? always include error in the question

Comment: `GetInt64()` returns a `long`. What is the datatype of the column in the sql table?

Comment: Does `long` have a `ToArray` method? That doesn't sound right to me.

Comment: What is your table structure and what data contains it? What is the error you've faced?

Comment: I added error image and my datatype is bigint also added image from mssql and navicat .

Comment: You should include the error messages as text, not as image.

Comment: I added the error message as a text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your problem is data type mismatch.

reader gives you one value in every reader.Read() operation.

```
IList<long> myArray = new List<myArray>();

while (reader.Read())
{
    myArray.Add(reader.GetInt64(0));        
}
reader.Close(); 
reader.Dispose(); // always close and dispose your reader whenever you are done.    

long ns = Convert.ToInt64(textBox1.Text);
long sns = Convert.ToInt64(textBox2.Text);
long nsxp = lvl[ns];
long snsxp = lvl[sns];
long toplam = nsxp + snsxp;

for (int i = 0; i < lvl.Length; i++)
{
    if (toplam < lvl[i])
    {
        textBox3.Text = Convert.ToString(i - 1);
        break;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer but when I using your code i am taking error in `long nsxp = lvl[ns]` and error saying cannot convert long to int.

Comment: because ns and sns is long type, convert it to int

Comment: Thanks again and now i am taking new error about cannot convert object to int.

Comment: how did you declare your list? in which line are you getting error. check my answer again

Comment: I edit my answer. please check it. i missed a conversion

Comment: I changed all long values to int and taking error `Specified assignment is not valid` on line `lvl.Add((int)reader["Paragon"])`

Comment: you cannot use int since it is defined as long. can you update your code on question. so that we can see the latest version of it

Comment: if you believe that this answer is helpful, please consider to mark it as answer

Answer (score 0):

`SqlDataReader`'s `Read()` reads a single record from the database. You are trying to use it to read all records at once. This code illustrates an example of how to read each value sequentially:

```
while (reader.Read()) // This returns true if a record is available, and false once all records have been read.
{
    var paragonValue = reader.GetInt64(0); // This reads the current record's Paragon value.
    // Do something with paragonValue.
}
```

See the [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.read?view=netframework-4.7.2) on SqlDataReader.Read for more information.